# The keyword "this" can't be used in static methods

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, static-methods, this

I'm new in Flash programming.

I'm trying to rebuild my app structure with external classes.

In this process, I copied and pasted a block of my code that contains a for loop in an external class but I've got an error:

```
Impossibile to use the "this" keyword in static methods.
```

How can I convert my code to make it working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a class name instead of `this` , may be? Like `String.fromCharCode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your code by not using this inside your static function